# Laravel Multi-Auth system Auth::user() is returning null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I've done the multi-authentication system for admins and it's working fine. But when the admins logged in i want to show their names in the frontend header. I'm using `Auth::user()` but it's returning `null` even if the user(admins) are logged in. Below is the controller code for front-end

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
}

public function index(){
    // return view('frontEnd.homepage');
    return dd(Auth::user());
}
```

and if i don't use the middleware,then i can access the authenticated users(admins). but when admins are unauthenticated, it's preventing the access of the front-end page. how can i fix it ?

Comment: How you did the "multiauthentication system for admins": something written by you or that ships with laravel?

Comment: i've copied the guards of config\Auth.php and make admin guard. also make admin model and use that guard in the model. that's how...

Comment: Did you follow a tutorial or it's all done by yourself? in both cases it's better if you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Otherwise is a guess game to think an answer.

Comment: yeap, i followed a tutorial [devmarketer] chanel in youtube